# Graphics not working properly with Ubuntu 11.04 and later

Tags: 10.10, intel

My machine is Intel Integrated graphics G31/33, Core2duo, 3gb ram. I am currently using Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick. I have tried installing  latest versions of Ubuntu but none of them work properly. All of them have problem with my graphics.

Now, Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick is no longer supported. Is there a way it can be used safely for longer?

Comment: i suggest you to try a live usb or live cd. if they work fine then the graphics problem with ubuntu installation could possibly be solved. i myself am using 10.10 i had taken quite a lot of pain to make it smooth and pain-free and do not feel like upgrading. you can use 10.10 safely without worrying. to make it more safe you could use the inbuilt firewall.

Answer (score 0):

I felt the same way until I installed the gnome desktop, then things started working properly for me using 11.10. So, give 11.10 a try, but once installed open the Ubuntu Software Center and install GNOME Desktop Environment. All the funky effects will be gone and the user interface is like the 10.10

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting security updates anymore for 10.10, so I would say it's not safe any longer, but you can wait for the release of 12.04 and upgrade to that version. 10.10 reached the end of it's lifetime and no one else will be carrying the burden of supporting it.

If there is an option to install an additional graphics card, I would recommend you buy a (new) graphics card. It doesn't have to be top notch or even the newest generation, a low end to midrange model from the last 3 generations with passive cooling will suffice. You will get a nice Unity 3D desktop and with proprietary drivers probably even video acceleration.

If Unity is nothing for you 12.04 will provide the package [gnome-fallback-session](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/03/gnome-classic-in-ubuntu-12-04-its-like-nothing-ever-changed/).